# How can I access an expanded directory listing when saving a new document?

Tags: filesystem

When I save a new document, I can only choose the default save location or recently used locations, but sometimes I want to save in an existing directory I haven't visited recently. How can I expand the choices in the dialog box so I can select from any one of my existing directories?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have this savebox :

[image]

Just click on the arrow on the right.

The dialog will then expand to allow you to choose any destination.

Comment: Please make the question as solved by checking my answer (clic the tick on the left)

Answer (score 1):

You can tell OS X expand save dialogs by default by running this command in Terminal:

```
defaults write -g NSNavPanelExpandedStateForSaveMode -bool true
```

Quit and reopen applications to apply the changes.

If you have enabled iCloud and you haven't disabled syncing documents and data, applications like TextEdit and Preview use iCloud as the default location in save dialogs. You can disable that by running this command:

```
defaults write -g NSDocumentSaveNewDocumentsToCloud -bool false
```